# Deserializing nested JSON array using jackson

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson

In my app, I'm working with objects like this:

```
public class User {
  private String name;
  private int age;
}
```

I make a call to an API, and the response looks like:

```
{
  response: {
   result: [
     {
        name: x
        age: y
     },
     {
        name: x
        age: y
     },
    ...

  }
}
```

Somehow, I'd like to call `User[] users = restTemplate.getForObject(url, ...)` and get my list of users.
However, I'm unsure of how to parse the json response and create a list of `User`s using Jackson.
Anyone have suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Jackson can deal with [generic collections with POJO values](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/#3-minute-tutorial-generic-collections-tree-model):

```java
try {
    Map<String, Map<String, List<User>>> result = mapper.readValue(response, new TypeReference<Map<String, Map<String, List<User>>>>() {});
    
    List<User> users = result.get("response").get("result");
    for (User user : users) {
        System.out.println(user.getName());
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
public class User {
  private String name;
  private int age;
}
```

```java
class Response{
    private User[] result;
 // omitted getter and setter
}
```

```java
class OuterResponse{
    private Response response;
 // omitted getter and setter
}
```

```
OuterResponse outerResponse = restTemplate.getForObject(url, ...);
User[] users=outerResponse.getResponse().getResult();
```